# Using two AMD Graphics cards with crossfire where one was not rendering properly previously (corrupt memory?)

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I had a graphics card that wouldn't render properly. I think part of the memory was corrupt, there were 'lines and boxes' across the screen; it was a Radeon HD5770.

The new purchase, an AMD Radeon HD6770 is not getting quite enough frame rates to satisfy at the moment. Since both are cross-compatible with Crossfire if I gather correctly, **I'm wondering if I can connect the two, and output through the 'healthy' card.**

- Will this have a decent chance of working at all?
- Can I damage the 'good' card by connecting one with corrupt memory?

Comment: This sounds like more of a driver problem considering the HD6770 is several magnitudes better then the 5770.  You gain very little from putting the cards in Crossfire given the significant performance differences.

Comment: @Ramhound according to this http://www.game-debate.com/news/?news=10732&graphics=Radeon+R9+290X&title=Complete+List+Of+AMD+CrossFire+GPU+Combinations page it should work...

Comment: I never said it didn't. I just said you would gain very little performace increases by doing so. I also said your current performance problems are a driver issue.  I personally would not use the 5770 if you suspect it has already failed.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for the input, figured both had the same amount of RAM so it might give a boost :/ ...